# Which type of filter gives the smallest filter order?

Tags: digital-filters

In a lowpass digital filter if I have passband and stopband ripples, passband and stopband edge frequencies.

Which type of filter, IIR or FIR, will give the smaller filter order?

Comment: IIR will generally have the lower order.  But order of the filter is rarely the only design constraint.

Comment: @StephenRauch: care to explain in detail about what all other things to consider so that i can mark that as correct answer?

Comment: Would love to, but... That is a **Huge** question.

Comment: @StephenRauch: just explaining the reason as why IIR will have lower filter order will do.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_impulse_response#Advantages_and_disadvantages

Comment: "Why the IIR has the lowest order" Math. In fact, *a lot of math*. Far too much for an answer here, if you don't explain how much algebra and system theory you already know – because with all you say, we'd have to start explaining linear systems, and that's basically a full 300-page textbook before we can even get to filter design

Answer (score 1):

In most cases an elliptic filter (also known as  Cauer filter) will give you the lowest order https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_filter

That's simply due to to the fact that it allows you to adjust both pass band ripple and stop band attenuation at the same time. If you care most about filter order, you can sacrifice pass band ripple and stop band attenuation to whatever degree your specific application can tolerate.

Comment: We should also add that an elliptic filter will have significant phase dispersion (non-linear phase), especially in vicinity of the pass band edge.

Comment: @DanBoschen; that's true for all IIR filters. The max group delay is more or less proportional to the steepness of the roll  off

Comment: While all IIR filters have non linear phase, you can well approximate linear phase such as the Lerner filter. My point was that Elliptic filters are amongst the worst for phase dispersion. There are several other choices for IIR filters that will not be as dispersive (and as you point out will not have as sharp as a cutoff).

Comment: @DanBoschen … nearly all IIR filters have nonlinear phase :) CICs!

Comment: Yes! Good one @MarcusMüller.  I wonder if you can really classify a CIC as an IIR? It has an IIR structure certainly but in the end as you know is an all zero filter. Thoughts? Do you know of others with zeros that aren't perfectly cancelled? Perhaps a good question for the proof as to why that can't (or perhaps can) exist!

Comment: Well, coming to think of it, I'm actually wrong: CICs are *recursive*, but have *finite* impulse response...

Comment: Ah someone asked the question already: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/7943/could-anybody-explains-me-why-iir-filters-do-not-have-linear-phase

Comment: @DanBoschen: my point was about the relationship between steepness and group delay. That's more or less the same for all filter types, it's not inherently worse for Ellipitic filters. You just need to compare at "same steepness" not "same order" There is actually a mathematical reason behind that.

Comment: @Hilmar  Agreed, no argument there but that is not what my comment was about. Elliptic filters have the most phase dispersion. Note that that is not the group delay but the group delay variation. For example, consider that you can have a very steep linear phase filter which will have a long delay but no phase dispersion.  :)